# Angular watching a function with parameter values

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I'm iterating through a list of `Jobs` Like this, (simplified for demonstration).

I can access the information from the `Jobs` array super easy, like this (Job.Name, Job.Date, etc.)

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, Job) in Jobs" ng-show="Job.Status=='Active'">
    <div class="newMessages">
        {{hasNewCreatorMessages(Job.$id)}} New Messages
    </div>
</div>
```

However I created a function to count the number of messages left on that job that I'm accessing like a variable above, here is the full function:

```
$scope.hasNewCreatorMessages = function(jobID) {
        var numNewMessages = 0;
        var messages = firebase.child('messages');
        messages.on('value', function(snap){
            snap.forEach(function(child){
                child.forEach(function(message){
                    if(jobID == message.val().jobID && message.val().newCreatorMessage) {
                        numNewMessages += 1;
                    }
                });
            });
        });
        console.log(numNewMessages);
        return numNewMessages;
    };
```

The console outputs the correct number of new messages (so the counter and function are working correctly).  The problem is that in the actual html view it doesn't update, I have a feeling it has to do with the Angular Digest (which I don't fully understand).  Sometimes when I access the page from the cache it works properly, but if I do a hard refresh it doesn't display the count.

Comment: This is a pretty big mess. Are you using AngularFire here? The `$id` suggests so. Where is the rest of the code explaining what Jobs is and how it's created. It's going to be extremely difficult to offer any meaningful advice here. See [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your function `$scope.hasNewCreatorMessages` is only run when the dom is parsed by angular, or when your `$scope.Jobs` is updated (the root object, not the children).

In order to solve your issue, inside your controller, you should add a `$watch` wich will trigger a function that will update an array inside your `$scope` :

Inside your controller, when it gets instanciated, you do something like that :

```
$scope.arrayOfCounters = [];

for (var i = 0; i< $scope.Jobs.length; i++){
     $scope.arrayOfCounters.push(integerCalculatedByAFunction);
}
```

Then, you register a watch to your jobs

```
$scope.watchCollection('Jobs.something.messages', function(){
    //Update your array here

    //Do not $scope.arrayOfCounters = [];   <= this creates a new reference and the view wont be updated.
    // But do instead $scope.arrayOfCounters.length = 0;
});
```

Sorry for the lack of explanation around `watchCollection`, I now it exists, but have never used it.